# Has "eponymous" been used correctly?

Tags: meaning

Listening to the Test Match Special commentary (on the cricket match currently underway between England and Australia), I heard the commentator Henry Blofeld complain that the English batsman -Wood- had given a rather "wooden performance". He followed it up with "to employ an eponymous description".

Was this a correct use of *eponymous*? The expression "wooden performance" already exists - so he wasn't coining the term by use of the subject's name. Had he described a performance by Jones as a *Jonesian innings* - that would have been eponymous. I would have said he had created a *pun* rather than to have spoken *eponymously*.

Purely incidental to this *faux pas*, Blofeld himself has a curious connection with the eponymous. The name of the master criminal, Blofeld, who appears in every James Bond thriller, was created by Iain Fleming after the name of Henry Blofeld's father - the two of them having been at Eton together.

Comment: I would say it is reasonable _to_ call this eponymous, though _pun_ also applies. He has still used the name of _Wood_, just extended it to match a common phrase. A bit of artistic licence is often called for.

Comment: If wooden performances had been named for him, then yes. But that is not the case.

Comment: @Robusto Indeed. Why don't you supply that as an answer?

Comment: @Ws2: Very well, if you insist.

Comment: it's nothing but irony.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If wooden performances had been named for him, then yes. But that is not the case.

Comment: Can't put it any more succinctly than that! But I would have some sympathy with Henry Blofeld if one of his co-commentators had picked him up over an "incorrect usage".

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps he said 'epunymous'.

> Epunymous Title
>
> This is the unsettling habit of giving something a
> title which is a pun on the lead character's name — particularly if
> the character's name reflects the work's premise and/or theme. For
> example, in a TV series named Swift Justice you can pretty much bet
> that our hero will be named something like "Jane Justice" or "John
> Swift" (or, Heaven help us, Federal District Court Judge "Justice
> Alice Swift").
>
> http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EpunymousTitle

Comment: TVTropes is worse than Wikitionary in terms of being a credible source. The terminology found on that site is effectively headcanon for people who take categorization far too seriously.

Comment: Haha - I read that  as 'headcarrion'! :-) Either I need new glasses or I should enter the word on TVTropes. Okay maybe I'm wrong but 'epunymous' does work quite well even if it isn't a real word.